# I want to freeze header part (Header, logo etc) in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, header

I want to freeze header part (Header, logo etc) in wordpress. I mean when I scroll the page the header should be in fixed position and rest of the page should scroll up and down. I want a theme independent solution, so that it could be used in any thme.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to create a theme independent solution because it is impossible to guess the markup of somebody else's html.

The best you can do is analyze the current theme's html/css structure and convert it to fixed. If you need help doing that then please post your site's html.

You could insert your own header, and push the rest of the content down by applying margin to the body and fixing your own content. Wordpress does this when displaying its admin bar.

```
body { margin-top: 30px; }
div.yourheader { height: 30px; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen CSS's `position: fixed`?

It would be hard for this to be theme-independent because of the html/css structure defined by the writer/designer of the theme.